# react js react-boostrap toggling menu buttons not working

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am reading the examples on react-bootstrap for Navbar Nav controls on https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/. My current menu button are not toggle at all.

I read some of the post here but they are all using the same code example like

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
      <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
    <Nav>
      <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
        Dank memes
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

I have the following code that is not toggling buttons

```
<Navbar>
  <Navbar.Brand /> // tried this but does not fix it
  <Nav>
    {menuButtonList} // this is any array of menu buttons that include 'Home'
  </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

The current issue, by default Home button is highlighted as active. When I clicked on the other menu buttons, they highlight and toggle. The first button, Home, stays active.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you are missing `NavBar.Toggle` and `NavBar.Collapse`

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `Home` is expected to keep highlighted because it's a `Navbar.Brand` component not a `Nav.Link`. A `Navbar.Brand` is expected to behave like that, it's related to what a `Brand` is all about. When you display your `Brand` you expect that it shines to reinforce your `Brand`.

if you don't want a `Brand` than it's better to switch to another `Nav.Link` nested at you `Nav` component instead.

Comment: It also does not work if I removed the Brand

Comment: I added the Toggle and removed it. i also added the Brand with no parameter. The Home button seems to be active by default. How do I change that behavior

Answer (score 0):

finally figure it out, its the navitem home URL property, updated it from "/" to "/home". After url update, the home menu button will allow toggling.